Relationship between MGF and Expected Values
I am trying to understand the relationship between Moment Generating Functions (MGF) and Expected Values.
Here is my attempt to show this.
The moment generating function $ M_X(t) $ of a random variable $ X $ is defined as:
$$ M_X(t) = \mathbb{E}[e^{tX}] $$
For the first derivative of $ M_X(t) $ with respect to $ t $, we can use the definition of the derivative and the properties of expectation.
The first derivative of $ M_X(t) $ is:
$$ M_X'(t) = \frac{d}{dt} M_X(t) = \frac{d}{dt} \mathbb{E}[e^{tX}] $$
Using the linearity of expectation, we can move the derivative inside the expectation:
$$ M_X'(t) = \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{d}{dt} e^{tX}\right] $$
The derivative inside the expectation is straightforward, since $ X $ is not a function of $ t $:
$$ \frac{d}{dt} e^{tX} = X e^{tX} $$
Thus, we have:
$$ M_X'(t) = \mathbb{E}[X e^{tX}] $$
Now, we evaluate this derivative at $ t = 0 $:
$$ M_X'(0) = \mathbb{E}[X e^{0 \cdot X}] = \mathbb{E}[X \cdot 1] = \mathbb{E}[X] $$
Therefore, the first derivative of the moment generating function evaluated at $ t = 0 $ is the expected value of $ X $:
$$ M_X'(0) = \mathbb{E}[X] $$
Is this why the derivative of the MGF results in the Expected Value?

Yes, that's right (once you take care of convergence issues). Similarly the higher derivatives get you the higher moments.
